# Angular 6 - Styles are not working when using ng-content

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have some code and I'm having issues with the css which is not targetting when using `<ng-content></ng-content>`

Here is the code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-embed',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
  styles: [`

  app-embed {
    position:relative;
     width:100%;
     height:0;
     padding-bottom:33%;
  }

 app-embed iframe {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 56.25vw;
  }`]
})
export class AppEmbedComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the styles of the content in the component that embeds them. If you want to style the `AppEmbedComponent` tag then you need to use the `:host` psuedo selector to do so.

embed.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-embed',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
  styles: [`
    :host {
      position:relative;
      width:100%;
      height:0;
      padding-bottom:33%;
    }
  `],
})
export class AppEmbedComponent {}
```

other.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-other',
  template: `
    <app-embed>
      <iframe src="//www.google.com"></iframe>
    </app-embed>
  `,
  styles: [`
    iframe {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 56.25vw;
    }
  `],
})
export class AppOtherComponent {}
```

## [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fs59fu)